# Nuget pack does not carry dependency versions correctly

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have Nuget packages created from two projects: `foo.csproj` and `bar.csproj`. When using `nuget update`, I would like `bar` to update `foo` to the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards) matching 3.0.*, and reject any 3.1.*:

**bar packages.config**

```
<packages>
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="foo" version="3.0.4" targetFramework="net472" allowedVersions="3.0" />
</packages>
```

**bar.nuspec**

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>var</id>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <!-- omitted -->
    <!-- no dependency node in this .nuspec file - good, I think -->
  </metadata>
</package>
```

and in my Nuget feed I have:

- foo.3.0.0.nupkg
- foo.3.0.1.nupkg
- foo.3.0.2.nupkg
- foo.3.0.3.nupkg
- foo.3.0.4.nupkg

If I call `nuget update`, it updates the `packages.config` file correctly - yay!

However, when I call `nuget pack bar.csproj`, it generates a .nupkg file that includes the following **bar.nuspec** file:

```
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>var</id>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
    <!-- omitted -->
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.1" />
      <dependency id="foo" version="3.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

I expected `nuget pack` to abide by the **packages.config** `allowedVersions` attribute when generating the `dependency` node inside the .nupkg file.

How do I get `nuget update` and `nuget pack` to work together to keep bar up to date with the latest 3.0.* version of `foo` (in this example, 3.0.4)?

Answer (score 0):

I expect it will work as you desire if you remove the `allowedVersions` attribute from your `packages.config` file.

Comment: Agreed that would fix the 3.0.0 problem, but I believe I would then lose the ability to have `nuget update` update to the latest 3.0.*, but reject 3.1.*.  (I will update my question to make that goal clear.)